# c++ static member in scala generic programming

Tags: scala, generics

I used to be a c++ programmar and new to scala.
And I what to do some generic programming in scala such as

```
   class FooComponent
    {
     public:
       static const int ComponentId = 1;
    }
    class BarComponent
    {
     public:
       static const int ComponentId = 2;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void registerComponent()
    {  
       register(T::ComponentId)
    }
```

But in scala there is no class static variable. I know there is companion object, but I can not access the companion object by just a type parameter.

What is the correct way to achive similar function in scala?

Comment: not a c++ programmer, don't you have to say that `FooComponent` inherits the template?? also when you do `T::ComponentId`, T does not even have `ComponentId`?? _you can ignore my question obviously I don't know c++ templates :)_

Comment: @prayagupd - A call of the type `registerComponent<BarComponent>()` will instantiate a function with the body `register(BarComponent::ComponentId)`. `T` is a *stand-in* for a type here, not any specific one.

Comment: @prayagupd You are right about that. It does not know whether T have ComponentId or not. But when you try to instantiate a function with a type T which does not have ComponentId, it will throw a compile error

Comment: that looks interesting, so you can call `template` which has no definition of `ComponentId` in it, and it would compile. My guess was template is closer to interface in scala/java/OO, where you predefine what you going to have in your implementation classes.

Comment: my attempt, not exactly c++ template copy, somewhat closer https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/s5CPeKhsTs2hkg96fwDGKg/1

Answer (score 0):

You can come close to this using structural typing. But as far as I know you can not combine it with static members from a companion object.

```
class FooComponent{
  val ComponentId = 1
}

class BarComponent{
  val ComponentId = 2
}

object Main extends App{
  def register(t: {val ComponentId:Int} ) = println(t.ComponentId)

  register(new BarComponent())  // -> 2
  register(new FooComponent())  // -> 1
}
```

If you need access from both instance and class objects you could do this:

```
class FooComponent{
  val ComponentId = FooComponent.ComponentId
}
object FooComponent{
  val ComponentId = 1
}

class BarComponent{
  val ComponentId = BarComponent.ComponentId
}
object BarComponent{
  val ComponentId = 2
}

object Main extends App{
  def register(t: {val ComponentId:Int} ) = println(t.ComponentId)

  register(BarComponent)      // -> 2
  register(new BarComponent)  // -> 2
  register(FooComponent)      // -> 1
  register(new FooComponent)  // -> 1

  println(FooComponent.ComponentId)   // -> 1
}
```

Comment: Can I just extract the id without newing an object?

Comment: For statics you need a companion object with the same name e.g. object BarComponent. If you put your val there it can be accessed without creating an instance.

Comment: I understand your solution, it will sovle the problem, but I wonder if there is a better way. Because in your solution, you have to pass in an object, and you get the componentId in this object at **runtime**, while in the c++ example, there is no need to pass in an object and all the componentId will be determined at **compile time**

Comment: I'm not sure if you can exactly rebuild your example in Scala. Maybe there is a (more complicated) way to do this which I don't see.

Comment: If you don't need to call register() with instances  you don't need the classes for this. I'm not exactly sure what you really want to archive but maybe there is a better Scala-like way to do the same without the use of static component IDs. e.g. you could use the type or companion directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use type parameters only (and be more template-like) you could do it with a macro:

Create the actual macro in a Macro project

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object MyMacroImpl {
 def registerMacro[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.universe.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
  val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companion

  q"""MyMacro.register(${companion.name.toTermName}.componentId)"""
```

}

Use the macro in your project

```
class FooComponent
object FooComponent {
  val componentId: Int = 1
}

class BarComponent
object BarComponent {
  val componentId: Int = 2
}

object MyMacro {
  def registerComponent[T]: Unit = macro MyMacroImpl.registerMacro[T]
}

object Main {
  def register(id: Int): Unit = println(id)

  MyMacro.registerComponent[FooComponent]
}
```

Edit: Personally, I would just implement it like this:

```
def register(id: Int): Unit = println(id)

trait HasComponentId {
  def componentId: Int
}

class FooComponent
object FooComponent extends HasComponentId {
  override val componentId: Int = 1
}

class BarComponent
object BarComponent extends HasComponentId {
  override val componentId: Int = 2
}

def registerComponent(comp: HasComponentId): Unit =
  register(comp.componentId)


assert(registerComponent(FooComponent) == 1)
```

No macros (and thus much less complexity), no instantiation of objects and the result is pretty much the same.

Comment: I'm not famliar with macro in scala but the code looks like what I what. Thanks for your answer and I will try the macro way.